# Unable to perform a POST request in php using cURL

Tags: php, curl, ldap

I am unable to perform a POST request in php, the following is my code:

```
 $ch = curl_init();
 $fields = "=var1?var2?var3";
 $url = "http://localhost/Profile.php?";
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,true);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$fields);
 $output = curl_exec($ch);
 curl_close($ch);
```

profile.php:

```
print_r($_POST);
```

Nothing seems to be displaying on the page just an empty array, if I do via GET it works. What have I done wrong?

Comment: You have to separate variables using ampersand(&), not ?. Like this: `var=&var2=&var3=

Comment: i tried that also, still same result nothing is displayed

Answer (score 1):

Your `$fields` string should be in the format `"key1=value1&key2=value2..."`, without a prepended `=`. So, in your case:

```
$fields = "key1=var1&key2=var2&key3=var3";
```

Additionally, the `print_r($_POST)` command in your code will render what has been POSTed *to* your page, not *by* your page.

Comment: so in order for the data to be displayed on the other page, what would you suggest?

Comment: You want to display the data that you *sent*, not the data you *received*, right?

Comment: You could `print_r($_POST)` on the page *to which* your script is posting. And now that I'm looking at it, that may be what you were trying to indicate by the line `profile.php: print_r($_POST);`. Did you mean that that line is in the separate script, profile.php?

Comment: yes profile.php is the script should be a seprator there sorry for the confusion

Comment: i did do it on the script and its prints out data, but thats not what i want as i want the data on the profile.php

Comment: What data do you mean? Is there more to your profile.php script that you didn't post here?

Comment: no profile.php just has a print_r($_POST); statement, i meant the data i passed in through curl is printed out on the same page not profile.php

Comment: Well, the variable `$fields` contains what the script passes to `curl`, so `echo $fields;` would show you what the current script is about to send via POST. Is that what you mean?

Comment: no, i did a print_r($_POST); in profile.php and i expected the data to be displayed in profile.php and yet nothing, i did the exact for GET and it worked.

Comment: Just for fun: are you sure you have cURL support installed for PHP on your local machine?

Comment: yes absolutely certain. i have done this with GET request in curl so yes

Comment: ive updated my code and i still get the same result.

Answer (score 0):

```
//set POST variables
$url = 'http://domain.com/get-post.php';
$fields = array(
                        'lname' => urlencode($last_name),
                        'fname' => urlencode($first_name),
                        'title' => urlencode($title),
                        'company' => urlencode($institution),
                        'age' => urlencode($age),
                        'email' => urlencode($email),
                        'phone' => urlencode($phone)
                );

//url-ify the data for the POST
foreach($fields as $key=>$value) { $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; }
rtrim($fields_string, '&');

//open connection
$ch = curl_init();

//set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);

//execute post
$result = curl_exec($ch);

//close connection
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: nothing gets displayed on the following page, when i try this.